# What is *BindW*?

Tags: windows

I am looking at a windows library in IDA pro and I came across a function call

```
BindW(ushort **, void **)
```

IDA pro adds the comments *Binding* and *StringBinding* respectively to the parameters when they are pushed.

What is this function?

Comment: Double-click on the BindW function call to see where it is in the Import Table in order to find out the DLL that exports it.

Comment: @JasonGeffner looks like it is not imported at all. It is part of crypt32.dll which is what I was looking at in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an undocumented non-exported function. Hex-Rays output is:

```
RPC_STATUS __stdcall BindW(RPC_WSTR *StringBinding, RPC_BINDING_HANDLE *Binding)
{
  RPC_STATUS result; // eax@1

  result = RpcStringBindingComposeW(0, L"ncalrpc", 0, L"protected_storage", 0, StringBinding);
  if ( !result )
    result = RpcBindingFromStringBindingW(*StringBinding, Binding);
  return result;
}
```